# Sum of roots of $\frac{8\sin^2x\cos x - \sqrt{3}\sin x - \cos x}{\sin{(x + \frac{7\pi}{2})} - \sqrt{3}\cos{(x-\frac{3\pi}{2}})} = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

**MY MATH PROBLEM IS**

How to find the **sum of all possible result** of
$$\frac{8\sin^2x\cos x - \sqrt{3}\sin x - \cos x}{\sin{(x + \frac{7\pi}{2})} - \sqrt{3}\cos{(x-\frac{3\pi}{2}})} = 0 \tag*{Eq.(*)} \label{Eq}$$ for $x$ in range $[0,1007\pi]$

- I just can find solution for the equation and I have no idea about the sum

$$\sin\left(x + \frac{7\pi}{2}\right) - \sqrt{3}\cos\left(x - \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \neq 0$$
So

$x \neq \frac{\pi}{6} + k2\pi $ and $x \neq \frac{5\pi}{6} + k2\pi$

while $k$ is any integer

$$\ref{Eq} \iff 4\sin{x}\sin{2x} - \sqrt{3}\sin{x} - \cos{x} = 0$$
$$\iff -2(\cos{3x} - \cos{x}) - \sqrt{3}\sin{x} - \cos{x} = 0$$
$$\iff \sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{2} + 3x\right) = \sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$x = \frac{\pi}{6} + k2\pi $ (**Removed**) or $x = \frac{5\pi}{12} + k2\pi$  (**Taken**)

We have $$0\le\frac{5\pi}{12} + k2\pi\le1007\pi$$
$$\frac{-5}{24}\le k \le \frac{12079}{24}$$
$$k \in [0,503]$$

Till here, i don't know how to find the sum. Please give me some **HINT** for this problem

Comment: [This tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might be helpful for your future questions and answers.